# TimeZone with SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I Usig SpringBoot and try to convert this return to my object

```
...
{
      "data": "2015-05-29",
      "codigo": 618393,
      "apresentante": null,
      "total": 6,
      "desconto": 0,
      "pago": 6
    },
...
```

so I have one object with

```
private Date data;
```

and I have one SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println(sdf.format(myObjet.getData()));
```

And print

28/05/2015, but the correct are 29/05/2015

my application.properties have this lines:

```
spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd
spring.jackson.time-zone=America/Sao_Paulo
```

anyone know why this happen?
tks

Comment: What is data.getTime() before it is formatted?

Comment: when I debug the date are 2015-05-28 (wrong too)

Comment: What is your default timezone? If you expect the formatted date to be the same as the one in the JSON, then you should format it using the same timezone as the one Jackson uses to parse it.

Comment: What is the timezone of your jvm ? you can print sdf.getTimeZone()

Comment: com.ibm.icu.impl.OlsonTimeZone@2d282381[transitionCount=130,typeCount=3,transitionTimes=[-1767214412,-1206957600,-1191362400,-1175374800,-1159826400,-6338196008,0,-10800,0,-10800,3600],typeMapData=[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,finalStartYear=2039,finalStartMillis=2.1774528E12,finalZone=SimpleTimeZone: America/Sao_Paulo]

Comment: spring.jackson.deserialization.adjust_dates_to_context_time_zone=false ?

Or may be remove this spring.jackson.time-zone=America/Sao_Paulo 
& try if you are getting it right ?

Or which Jackson version you are using ? Update your version to latest and try

Comment: And, you use `dd/MM/yyyy` to parse `2015-05-29`. That is wrong and will not work.

Comment: use `LocalDate` instead of `Date` type

Answer (score 0):

First, you suspect the Jackson configuration interferes with the `SimpleDateFormat` parsing/formatting, but it is wrong: **although Jackson uses `SimpleDateFormat` to parse/format code, the configuration of `spring.jackson.*` will not affect each and every `SimpleDateFormat` instance you create in the application.** They are two separate things.

You must use an `ObjectMapper`, and `@Autowired`, to use some context configurations; although I suspect, as I observed, `spring.jackson.time-zone` config does not affect the result of parsing/formatting of json/Date, i.e., **Jackson internally does not use this value in serialization/deserialization.**

My conclusion is that neither `spring.jackson.time-zone` either `mapper.setTimezone()` will affect the processing of timezone conversion in the (de)serialization, when we set `@JsonFormat(timezone = "xxx")`; the latter seems to override the former two; and, the default timezone of application will be the "target" timezone when converting.

I suggest you to attach another short but complete test case to show what is working and what is not.

Check this test of mine, and try to post a complete test like this:

```
@Test
public void testSimpleDateFormat() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("The default timezone is: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    String ds = "2015/05/29";
    Date d = f.parse(ds);
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

Be sure to begin with easy tests and add more variables into it little by little.

Answer (score 0):

**Use LocalDate and add the zone you need**

```
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
         String date = "16/08/2016";
       LocalDate   localDate=  ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.parse(date, 
                  formatter), ZoneId.of("Europe/Helsinki")).toLocalDate();
```